# how to install Conky Manager on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, conky

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Installing Conky Manager with these commands failed with "Dependency is not satisfiable: realpath".

```
sudo apt install conky-all
cp /etc/conky/conky.conf ~/.conkyrc
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install conky-manager
wget https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/conky-manager_2.4~136~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi conky-manager*.deb
```

Do you know how to resolve the dependency on "realpath"?

Comment: There has been no active development to `conky-manager` since 2016, and apparently one program `realpath` that was available in the repros then isn't available any longer. It will not be easy to recreate it either - see e.g. the discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101080/realpath-command-not-found). You may contact the developer through his [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008).

Comment: And you shouldn't, generally speaking, attempt to install software (from ppas or otherwise) that aren't available for your OS version.

Comment: have installed conky on ubuntu 18.04 and it works fine! I don't understand **why** you want to install it via external ppa. It works fine with standard packages.

Comment: @abu_bua Likely there's an expectation (correct or otherwise) that Conky Manager will shorten or eliminate the learning curve that accompanies attempts to customize Conky.

Answer (score 11):

You can install it with a `.run` file from GitHub.

For 64 bit:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases/download/v2.4/conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.run
chmod +x conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.run
sudo ./conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.run
```

For 32 bit:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases/download/v2.4/conky-manager-v2.4-i386.run
chmod +x conky-manager-v2.4-i386.run
sudo ./conky-manager-v2.4-i386.run
```

Answer (score 2):

Install realpath first and then install Conky Manager.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/realpath

Comment: Artful is 17.10, right?  If realpath is in 17.10 but not in (bionic) 18.04, there's probably a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on building conky manager for 4 hours and I'm very experienced in building packages.

But building conky manager was a trip down a road I don't wont to go again LOL.

I highly advise whoever wants to install it on Kubuntu or Ubuntu 18.04 to go with answer 4,

It ran flawlessly on Kubuntu and Ubuntu 18.04 fully updated. I just had to try it.

But I also need to say that if anyone was wanting to learn how to build packages from sources, that you would learn a lot from building conky manager and have a lot of fun too.

https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eteejee2008/conky-manager/trunk

Or from GitHub:

https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager

Comment: "answer 4" is ambiguous. which author's answer do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Donwload realpath in **[here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/realpath/download)**,
download conky manage in **[here](https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases)**
install with GDEBI or dpkg :

> sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb

I have written a post about how to install the conky manager on ubuntu 18.04, along with the error that I found on this [**site**](https://www.fosslicious.com/2018/05/how-to-install-conky-and-conky-manager.html). May be useful.

Answer (score 0):

a tentative answer:

1° install conky:

```
sudo apt-install conky
```

2° download realpath: [link to realpath](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/realpath/download)

3° download the conky manager: [this is the link](https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases)

4° install realpath and then conky:

```
sudo dpkg realpath_8.26...(the rest of the name you can copy paste in the terminal)
sudo dpkg conky...(id.)
```

5° then:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

6°launch conky manager from activities.

hope this works for you.

***leave long and prosper.***

Answer (score 0):

I'm using debian and this commands worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all
sudo apt-get install realpath
wget https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases/download/v2.4/conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i conky-manager-v2.4-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the first reply but then I got the error:

```
conky-manager: error while loading shared libraries: libgee-0.8.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then from

```
ldd /usr/bin/conky-manager
```

I got

```
libgee-0.8.so.2 => not found
```

and I solved with the command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/conky-manager/libs/libgee.so.2 /usr/share/conky-manager/libs/libgee-0.8.so.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I've managed to compile conky-manager and make it run on Raspbian/buster with the following:

```
sudo apt install build-essential valac libjson-glib-dev libgtk-3-dev libgee-0.8-dev imagemagick p7zip p7zip-full
git clone https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager.git
cd conky-manager
make && make install
```

This should work on ubuntu 18.04 too.