# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS don't install Conky Manager

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 18.04, conky, budgie

I need to install Conky Manager to add themes and change settings  to make my own preferences on a desktop screen. However when I type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install conky-manager
```

My Ubuntu says to me that I'm unable to find conky manager package. Can anyone help me to install Conky Manager to personalize my desktop screen properly? Thanks!:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install Conky Manager on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038805/how-to-install-conky-manager-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: There are three answers on the duplicate candidate above. Although none are accepted by OP there, hopefully one or more solutions work for OP here.

Comment: My question is not about how to install conky cause I've found commands that works for someone.My question is to solve the problem about what this command isn't works and what is the correct command.I didn't know what to do before and I read that post that don't solve my problem.N0rbert had a crystal ball to conky manager run in my system.

Comment: I've retracted the close vote. At the time I voted, I did not yet see N0bert's answer with great screenshots and references.

Comment: Hello guys! I have an issue when I download a ppa that I think it may cause some bugs when I run skins.When I add this the system give me the following error:  `  Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pegiiaa/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
`

Comment: I have another doubt here about this bugs:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079883/conky-for-ubuntu-budgie-18-04-1-lts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with analysis of this PPA problem. You are going to install `conky-manager` package, so you know exact name and target Ubuntu version.
In such case you should use special PPA search page on launchpad.net - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas with the corresponding [search query "`conky-manager`"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=conky-manager). This page will return search results. You should click all these links one-after-one and select *Published in: Bionic* filter. You can choose any PPA which you trust more.
Other way is to use [Y PPA Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000768/66509).

I ended with this one ([`ppa:mark-pcnetspec/conky-manager-pm9`](https://launchpad.net/%7Emark-pcnetspec/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager-pm9)) as it has `realpath` package in PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mark-pcnetspec/conky-manager-pm9
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

After installation you will get Conky Manager 2.4 running on your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

[image: Conky Manager 2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

---

Note: packages from two other PPAs ([`ppa:marius.quabeck/nerdzoom`](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarius.quabeck/+archive/ubuntu/nerdzoom) and [`ppa:tomtomtom/conky-manager` (20.04 LTS compatible)](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager?field.series_filter=bionic)) are really depends on `realpath` package (as were [noted by @OrganicMarble](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079606/66509)), but do not include it.

Comment: Yeah! It works! Thank you very much to anwsering for me! Hey Organic Marble and WinEunuuchs2Unix it works! N0rbert has a crystal ball! I wanna share the screenshot to you but I don't know how to do it here yet!

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry I didn't see your answer before I found the duplicate candidate. I would have abandoned researching. Could you port your answer to the duplicate candidate if this question gets closed in a day or two? +1

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix As we have only one close vote then you can retract it :) Thanks for your answer with live screenshot.

Comment: @N0rbert I will retract close vote but others may discover and VTC. In which case please port your answer over to the duplicate candidate if that happens :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm ready to port it :)

Answer (score 1):

This article [How to Install and Use Conky Manager on Ubuntu 16.04/17.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-conky-manager-ubuntu-16-04-17-04) should still work in Ubuntu 18.04.

You don't need to add the repository as conky is already in Ubuntu's repository. Simply follow these steps:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install conky-all
```

Once installed, you have to run Conky from the command line.

```
conky
```

You can modify conky to do your own preferences. Here's the top half of mine:

[image: nVidia GPU.gif]

---

Conky Manager isn't in Ubuntu 17.04's repository as the article mentions. As Organic Marble's answer states it isn't in 18.04's repository either. The article does say how to install it though:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/conky-manager_2.4~136~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi conky-manager*.deb
```

Comment: The question isn't about conky, it's about conky-manager, and you can't install that (at least not easily) in 18.04

Comment: @OrganicMarble I included another section from the article for the conky manager portion. I was under the impression the OP thought conky-manager was needed to run conky. I'm trying to point out conky-all will work from repository.

Comment: That method of installing conky-manager will not work in 18.04 due to missing dependencies.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I noticed the "realpath" dependency in your answer. I came across that a year or two ago and meant to research it. Unfortunately I've booted with 16.04 and need to reclone it to another partition and upgrade the clone to 18.04 before testing.

Comment: Hello WinEunuuchs2Unix! So,by these commands for 17.04 version conky manager didn't works.I think this happened cause my version is 18.04 as Organic Marble said.Meanwhile,I'm setting here to know how it works fine to me in a Tilix terminal.When I've used windows 8.1 the settings in rainmeter was similar to conky terminal.I'd like conky manager works ,but in a terminal I think I can manage my skins too and it's not so difficult as I thought.Thank you two to anwsering for me! :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble / J-Mello: the "realpath" dependency problem has been addressed in my answer now. If there are no other problems conky manager should work for you two. Thanks.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I didn't find the "real" realpath problem then. I'll roll back my edit. I could invest a couple of hours trying conky-manager in 18.04 only to discover it still won't work as you did. It doesn't seem worth the effort so we'll just leave it as using conky-all on version 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Conky-manager isn't in the ppa for 18.04 which is why you couldn't install it.

Unfortunately copying the .deb from 16.04 doesn't work either, because a dependency ("realpath") is missing.

It appears that getting conky-manager to work in 18.04 will not be easy.

It will probably be easier to edit your conky manually.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead. Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04, as of April 6, 2021.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/conky-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

Link to PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager)