# Conky for Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, lts, conky, budgie

I've had a downgrade on conky to fix the bugs.However,even with a 1.9.0-4 version it don't works as I expected.When I download some skins(the most of them) they don't appear on my desktop,have a bug when appear or even  Conky Manager don't recognize them!I need to know how to fix this issue cause Conky is the one of the some reasons that I moved to Ubuntu.These are all skins that I want to download by now: (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1189601/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1260394/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1210661/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006522/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006521/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1110721/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1111160/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1111468/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006024/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1111536/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006398/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006133/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006266/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006348/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1260394/)

Comment: Could you please add relevant information to your post: which skins do not work and from where we can download them? Also can try to read some good documentation from [the author](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/User-Configs) and from ArchLinux wiki ([Conky](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky) and [Conky/Tips and tricks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky/Tips_and_tricks)).

Comment: Ok! I will put here the links of specific skins that I want to download.

Answer (score 1):

As far I can understand from Conky Manager's source code it can install special prepared theme pack files (they are named `*.cmtp.7z`).

You can install such themes by pressing the corresponding button "Import Theme Pack (*.cmtp.7z)" on Conky Manager panel:

[image: Import Theme Pack (*.cmtp.7z) button location]

So you need to download such file from somewhere. I have tested theme named [*Arch Gotham*](https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1241354/) from OpenDesktop and it installs normally on my Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS (I do not have Budgie, desktop is not a problem in current case) with `conky-all` and `conky-manager` from [our previous Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079655/66509).

Other way to install is to download `*.cmtp.7z` file, then drag it and drop it to the Conky Manager window.

As the result you will get the window shown below

[image: Themes imported successfully]

and theme/widget will be added to the list and may be shown on desktop (if enabled):

[image: AMD BIOS - Arch Gotham is shown on desktop]

Also you can check big theme collection `Jesse_Supreme_conkys.cmtp.7z` from [Jesse Avalos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmdp/).

Notes:
1. pre-installed themes are also in the `*.cmtp.7z` format (their archive is placed in `/usr/share/conky-manager/themepacks/default-themes-2.1.cmtp.7z`).
2. Conky Manager does not help to install themes from other archive types, but will show location of their `conkyrc`- and `*.cmtheme`-files. You should use some manual methods to install such themes (simple copy of contents to `~/.conky` may work).

Comment: Do you know if have a way to convert the skins that I liked to the `*.cmtp.7z` format? I need a digital themes like crystal and clock that letters and numbers have a bright color like the following:(https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1006266/) 
 (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1111160/)  (https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1189601/).I will find something by your tips too! I want a website like opendesktop that have a lot of skins.Thanks to answering for me! :)

Comment: I need to tell you too what happened when I did a downgrade:Some skins suddenly appeared! Then,my system did an update and now I have the newer version again.This can be another issue also! My downgrade was to 1.9.0-4 as Corey Goldberg teach in this tutorial: (https://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/search?q=conky)  I didn't type the last command cause I don't know a way to revert it in case of future issues.