# Conky Manager Installation Problem

Tags: conky

I've done

```
sudo apt install conky-all
cp /etc/conky/conky.conf ~/.conkyrc
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
```

and then;

```
sudo apt install conky-manager
```

I get;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package conky-manager
```

How can I overcome this problem?Why I am unable to locate the package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS don't install Conky Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079596/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dont-install-conky-manager) and use [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080007/66509) to set it up.

Comment: I found my answer here,  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079596/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dont-install-conky-manager?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the repository, it appears that there is no conky-manager package available for any version of Ubuntu over 16.04.

Thus, as a workaround, you can simply edit the file 
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-$YOUR_DISTRO_NAME.list` and change it to look like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

After that, just run `sudo apt update` one more time and you should be able to install it no problem after that.

Mind you, `$YOUR_DISTRO_NAME` in the file name above depends on the version you are currently running. You can find out what that is by running: `lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: I've done what you said and now I get this; sudo apt install conky-manager
(Reading and Building depen. tree all done)
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-manager : Depends: realpath but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: By the way my distro name is bionic, if it helps